# How can I remove small part of collider of game object in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, masking, collider

[click here for gif show of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WQgq.gif)

I want to remove mesh of object when user click on object and also remove its  collider to make another object fall from that removed mesh area...
I am using unity since last month so I don't have much experience and knowledge, please help me...

Comment: First question... Does it need to be a single object with multiple meshes (or one mesh that is edited)? Alternatively could you use multiple objects? Doing it with meshes is possible but considerably more complex than just having two objects, one of which you make disappear. Also, your collision mesh should ideally be much lower resolution than the one you use for rendering, so do you know which parts of the mesh you'd want to remove (which faces/vertices)?

Comment: I want to do like this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WQgq.gif

Comment: Ok, to the best of my knowledge, you'll need to be editing a collision mesh then. Are you doing this in 2D or 3D? Editing a mesh at runtime is non-trivial. The Mesh object is really just an array of points (vertices) and faces (triangles). It will be your job to work out which vertices to remove based on where the user clicked, and how to re-stitch the faces so the mesh still looks good afterwards, without too much distortion. This may also involve managing/fixing up texture coordinates (UVs). This is a good intro: https://www.raywenderlich.com/3169311-runtime-mesh-manipulation-with-unity

Answer (score 0):

### Creating the destructable ground particles

One way to achieve whats shown in the gif is by creating a prefab of e.g. a circle collider that is instantiated in the area of where the dirt is in your gif. It acts as a "ground particle" and keeps the objects above itself.
You instantiate a lot of them in the area so it acts as a big collider although it is actually a whole array of smaller colliders.

### Implementing the interaction logic and deactivating the ground particles

Ater that you implement the functionality of dragging the mouse over the ground particles, removing them. That is also not difficult. Shoot raycasts into the screen at the postition of the mouse (remember to use Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint) and get the collision information (confer to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.Raycast.html). With the collision information you can get the reference to the instance of your ground particle(raycasthit.other.gameobject) which is then disabled through script(gameobject.setActive(false)).